# « Le japonais et moi, ça fait deux/trois/dix/mille/etc. » : Un nombre plus grand indique-t-il un lien encore plus ténu ?

Tags: expressions, nombres, hyperbole

> Le japonais et moi, ça fait **trois** / **dix** / **mille** !
>
> {vs} : Le japonais et moi, ça fait **deux** !

Je me demande si avec l'augmentation du nombre désigné dans « ça fait deux/trois/dix/mille/etc. », l'écart se creuse entre la langue japonaise et le locuteur ? Comme s’il s’y connaissait de moins en moins en japonais ? Je veux dire, est-ce que plus le nombre est élevé, plus cette expression insiste sur sa connaissance quasi nulle de la langue ?

Ou bien ne s'agissait-il que d’un petit jeu de mot de la part de quelqu’un qui s'était peut-être lassé de dire encore et toujours « ça fait deux » ?

Comment: Autre chose que *ça fait deux* peut être un effet de style humoristique (ex: **le calcul et moi, ça fait trois**), mais il est probable que dans beaucoup de cas, ce soit simplement une expression erronée due à la méconnaissance de sa signification originale.

Comment: De toute façon pour moi, le japonais c'est du chinois...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Je pense que l'expression est simplement *ça fait deux*. Toutefois pour appuyer encore le fait qu'on est très éloigné du sujet, on change parfois pour dire ça fait... trois ou mille (ou autre).

On peut dire, *le japonais et moi, ça (ne) fait même pas deux, ça fait plutôt 3, ou même 1000 !* Mais c'est là une sorte de clin d’œil à l'expression, une transgression de l'usage que l'on s'autorise en connaissance de cause, avec un interlocuteur qui lui aussi connait l'usage habituel de l'expression.

Answer (score 5):

L'expression en elle-même est supposée n'être utilisée qu'avec "deux" comme l'a précisé user8171079. Cependant, il est très courant, dans le langage parlé, d'entendre l'expression utilisée avec d'autres nombres. C'est en effet un moyen d'appuyer sur le sens et d'agrandir l'écart entre les deux parties. De la même façon que lors d'une journée particulièrement chaude on entend des exagérations comme: "Purée, il fait 10 000 degrés dans ce bus!".
"Le Français et moi ça fait 30 000" est juste une façon de suggérer un éloignement en plus de la separation des sujets.

Pour résumer, bien que n'ayant pas de sens littéral, l'utilisation à l'oral suggère en effet que plus le nombre est grand plus on considère les sujets éloignés.

Answer (score 1):

"Le japonais et moi ça fait deux" veut dire "il n'y a pas de lien entre le japonais et moi, nous sommes deux choses distinctes qui n'ont rien à faire l'une avec l'autre". Si l'on change ce nombre, l'expression perd son sens et devient illogique : pour que le japonais et toi fassent trois, il faudrait scinder une des deux parties (mathématiquement). Donc L'expression n'a de sens qu'avec deux.